# Can't get Guava using git-svn

Tags: git-svn, guava

The command

```
git svn clone http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ guava
```

fails after downloading about 20MB with the message

`r32 = 686b2497ca24c1a04fdc5c18aea1a02d03902d24 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
RA layer request failed:
  Server sent unexpected return value (502 Bad Gateway)
  in response to REPORT
 request for '/svn/!svn/vcc/default' at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 5117`

I get no master branch, nothing (which is understandable given the way git works). I'm using git version 1.7.3.3 under cygwin, XP64.

#### UPDATE:

I tried

```
git checkout 686b249
git branch master
git fetch
```

and it continues (currently r98).

#### UPDATE:

It finally finished. I myself vote for closing.

The only useful information:

```
Doing simply `git fetch` for resuming is the way to go.
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe the Google Code servers just got tripped up momentarily. AFAICT you didn't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of this open question, I answer it myself: This problem is gone forever, as they've [switched to git](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/checkout). Cool!